# Jquery .on Listener don't add click listener to new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having this problem (here I summarize) in which the Jquery .on method adds the listener to the first button that is created when loading the page but when the other is created by clicking the previous one the new button does not contain any listener although I indicated that it should look inside body for the element with the id that has the value of the variable count. According to the .on method you can add listeners to objects created later on the page.

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>



        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</head>
```

and here is script.js

```
var count = 1;

$("body").html("<button id=\"" + count +"\">1</button>");

$("body #" + count).on("click", function(){
    count++;
    $("body").html($("body").html() + "<button id=\"" + count +"\">" + count +"</button>");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var count = 1;

$("body").html("<button id=\"" + count +"\">1</button>");

$("body").on('click', '#' + count, function() {
    count++;
    $("body").html($("body").html() + "<button id=\"" + count +"\">" + count +"</button>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can define your function once, and it will execute for any dynamically added elements.

for example

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'body #' + count, function() {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: I always use **$(document).on();**

Comment: @StupidKid That's actually [not recommended by jQuery itself](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance), because the document is the topmost level object that receives all sorts of event, and it can be expensive to filter out all the events to cross-check the element that triggered it. In their own words: "Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents. One should only bind to the closest parent that is available at runtime, for performance reasons"

Comment: @Terry good to know, but sometimes when i load new data on page nothing works except with document.

Comment: @StupidKid Just bind it to the nearest parent element that is present at runtime ;) that should work. Let's say that `<form id="my-form">` is always present at runtime and you want to bind events to input elements that are dynamically added to it, instead of doing `$(document).on('change', ':input', ...)` you can do `$('#my-form').on('change', ':input', ...)`

Comment: Okay ill give a try! Thanks

Comment: @yajiv But why the only button that can generate more buttons is the first one if the variable count change it should make the last created button capable of generate more buttons?

Comment: @LucioCarrera reason is when `.on` was excuted the value of count is 1, so .on is excecuted like `.on('click','#1',..)` this and when we increse count it will not reflected to the `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.on()` works with elements that are added later to the page, only when it is bound to an element that already exists at runtime. In your example, the element that you're binding to `.on()` does not exist at runtime, hence there is no way that jQuery can bind the handler to dynamically added elements. Remember that `$el.on('click')` is basically the same as `$el.click()`.

What you want to do differently, is to **bind the `.on('click')` to an element, say the `<body>` element, that is always present at runtime**—that means you should change this:

```
$("body #" + count).on("click", function () {...});
```

...to this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#" + count, function () {...});
```

The `.on()` accepts an additional argument that allows the body to check, when it receives a click event, which element did it "bubble up" from. In this case, you tell the body:

1. Listen to the click event
2. When a click event is detected, execute the callback only when I know it has originated from an element with the ID of `count`

Comment: Trying this way the first button and the next ones that are created contain their respective listeners but the only one that can create buttons is the first button even if the others have their listeners

Answer (score 0):

In your script click event not called after the button element created. Try the below script.

```js
var count = 1;

$("body").html("<button id=\"" + count + "\">1</button>");

$("body #" + count).on("click", btnListener);

function btnListener() {
  count++;
  $("body").html($("body").html() + "<button id=\"" + count + "\">" + count + "</button>");
  $("body #" + count).on("click", btnListener);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</head>
```